# Javascript Conflicting Syntax Between Function As Object Key And Labeled Function in Block

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, labeled-statements

Assuming you have a browser that supports both [labeled function declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label#Labeled_function_declarations) and [block statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), what is the standard way/method for browsers to determine if the following is an object with a property named `L` that is function `F`, or a block that contains function `F` labeled as `L`:

```
{
    L: function F(){}
}
```

## E.g.

To expose what I mean, here are two different copies of the above code modified to expose it as an array and as a function:

```js
document.body.textContent = typeof( () => {
    L: function F(){}
} )
```

In the above code, the browser recognizes the arrow function notation and determines that it is a block statement. However,

```js
document.body.textContent = typeof {
    L: function F(){}
}
```

The above code makes the browser think that it is an object written out as an object literal with index `L` being function `F`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce the question to: How does the browser know whether `{` starts a **block** and when does it start an **object literal**?

And the answer to that is that JS engines will treat `{` as the start of a block if it appears in a statement position and as the start of an object literal if it is in an expression position.

That's the reason why you have to add parenthesis (`()`) around `{}` when they appear in a statement position but you want an object instead.

The introduction of labeled function declarations doesn't change the circumstances at all because the situation was already ambiguous:

```
{
  foo: 42
}
```

---

Looking at the spec again, this ambiguity is actually pointed out:

> An [*ExpressionStatement*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-expression-statement) cannot start with a U+007B (LEFT CURLY BRACKET) because that might make it ambiguous with a [*Block*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-Block).

(and the grammar reflects that too)

Comment: Could you please add a citation to where in the standards it says this. (I agree full-heartedly with this, but I am still curious about the gorey details)

Comment: It's not written as such in the spec, but it follows from the grammar rules: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations .

Comment: The parser simply tries to match rules. At the top you have a *Script*, which has as *ScriptBody*, which has a list of *Statement*s, etc.

Comment: An exception to this is the arrow notation. For example, with the arrow notation, if `() => 3` creates a function that returns 3, then logically `() => {
    L: function F(){}
}` should create a function that returns an object. But it isn't this way which means it must be more complicated.

Comment: Not that much more complicated, but yes, there are extra rules for arrow functions: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions . The body can either be an expression that does *not* start with `{` or it can be `{` followed by a list of statements, followed by `}`.

Comment: It is actually quite explicit in the spec. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well... I think that:

```
if(1){ // the brackets here belong to the if statement == block
    L: function F(){}
}
```

While here:

```
console.log({ // the brackets represent JSON (javascript object notation) 
    L: function F(){}
})
```

This is indeed an object with 'L' index

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You have just restated the examples. You do not appear to have listed any information about how the browser can tell them apart (in the very first snippet of code).

Comment: I do agree that the answer above is more detailed